# Prometheus metric kube_pod_status_reason returns hundreds of results, but all with a zero value - why?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I am using Prometheus and Grafana to monitor information on a Kubernetes cluster. I had hoped to use the `kube_pod_status_reason` metric for the reason why a given pod showed a "bad" state (i.e. not Running or Success).

However, if I run a plain PromQL query on this metric, I get hundreds of results, but every result has the value zero. It's been my experience with other metrics that return a 0 or 1 result, that a value of 1 means that is the current status.

Here's an example with a single pod with "Failed" status:

Query:

`kube_pod_status_reason{pod="runner-goew1uzh-project-8-concurrent-0zk79h"}`

Result:

| metric | value |
| --- | --- |
| kube_pod_status_reason{container="kube-state-metrics", endpoint="http", instance="10.244.211.138:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="runner-workspace-writer", pod="runner-goew1uzh-project-8-concurrent-0zk79h", reason="Evicted", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="0f42a95a-1065-4436-bfcf-432f57d0b55b"} | 0 |
| kube_pod_status_reason{container="kube-state-metrics", endpoint="http", instance="10.244.211.138:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="runner-workspace-writer", pod="runner-goew1uzh-project-8-concurrent-0zk79h", reason="NodeAffinity", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="0f42a95a-1065-4436-bfcf-432f57d0b55b"} | 0 |
| kube_pod_status_reason{container="kube-state-metrics", endpoint="http", instance="10.244.211.138:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="runner-workspace-writer", pod="runner-goew1uzh-project-8-concurrent-0zk79h", reason="NodeLost", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="0f42a95a-1065-4436-bfcf-432f57d0b55b"} | 0 |
| kube_pod_status_reason{container="kube-state-metrics", endpoint="http", instance="10.244.211.138:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="runner-workspace-writer", pod="runner-goew1uzh-project-8-concurrent-0zk79h", reason="Shutdown", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="0f42a95a-1065-4436-bfcf-432f57d0b55b"} | 0 |
| kube_pod_status_reason{container="kube-state-metrics", endpoint="http", instance="10.244.211.138:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="runner-workspace-writer", pod="runner-goew1uzh-project-8-concurrent-0zk79h", reason="UnexpectedAdmissionError", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="0f42a95a-1065-4436-bfcf-432f57d0b55b"} | 0 |

I've also noticed that regardless of which pod I choose to run this query for, not only do I get only a zero result, but I always get the same 5 "reasons". There's basically 5 records for every pod on the cluster, every one returning a zero value.

Is there something wrong with this metric, or am I completely misunderstanding its purpose?

Comment: I believe it is expected to behave in the same way as `kube_pod_status_phase` behaves: value of 1 is only for one, that is a correct reason/phase. I'm not sure why they all 0 though. Have you tried query like `kube_pod_status_reason > 0`?

Comment: Also, I doubt there is a reason for pod in phase Success. It kinda self evident what happened there.

Comment: If I run the query `kube_pod_status_reason > 0`, I get an empty result. Running it without the comparison, gets me well over 400 results, all zero. Weird.

Comment: Weird indeed. Since this metric is marked as experimental, if might be wise to create an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues) describing this behavior with specifics - it could be genuine bug.

Comment: Bug report submitted. https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/2116